# Custom Delete in Joomla Admin toolbar

Tags: joomla, admin, toolbar

I am trying to develop a admin tool for cleaning up the image map.
I already succeeded in putting all image information in the database and so using pagination and show thumbnail of all the images. Now I want to use the delete function to do two things:

- delete the entry of the image in the table
- delete the image in the image map.

The question is how to fix this.
I tried to make a `customdelete` in the toolbar:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('imapcleans.customdelete','delete.png','delete.png','d_s_cust');
```

And then added a function to the controller imapcleans:

```
public Function customdelete($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
    {
     // Get the input
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $pks = $input->post->get('cid', array(), 'array');

        // Sanitize the input
        JArrayHelper::toInteger($pks);

        // Get the model
        $model = $this->getModel();

        $return = $model->customdelete($pks);

        // Redirect to the list screen.
        //$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_imapclean&view=imapcleans', false));

    }
```

In the model I want to collect the information of the items to delete. But when I used something like this `$items = $this->items` it does not work.

Problem is maybe that the `getitems` is in the model `imapcleans` and the model `customdelete` is now in `imapclean`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just pass the param to your controller to model. why you are using like this->items ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jobin. I fixed it in another way. The trial version of the tool is available on http://www.jonker.co/downloadscat/image-map-cleaner